# Azure SQL Database, create a table through a script

Tags: azure, github, azure-sql-database, github-actions

I have a question regarding the **Azure SQL database**.

Is there anyway that we can create a table in Azure SQL database through a script.
Let's suppose that I provision it through terraform and I want to create a table as well while it is being provisioned through terraform.

So it can be fully automated.

Or is there any other option that we can create a table through github actions? because our code it on **github** and we are using **github actions** to provision our all azure resources.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "data_sql_server" {
  name                          = "data-sql-server-${var.env}"
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  version                       = "12.0"
  administrator_login           = var.mssql_db_username
  administrator_login_password  = var.mssql_db_password
  minimum_tls_version           = "1.2"
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  tags                          = var.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "data_sql_db" {
  name         = "data-sql-db-${var.env}"
  server_id    = azurerm_mssql_server.data_sql_server.id
  collation    = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb  = 250
  sku_name     = "S1"

  tags = var.common_tags
}
```

so here is the terraform code. What I want is, whenever it provisions the managed SQL server and managed database, it creates a table in the DB as well. So i don't have to create that table manually.

Comment: Is it SQL script or any other external script?

Comment: @Bhavani yes, I have just updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

so answer is

you need to create a file `.github/workflows/sql-deploy.yml`

add this code

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: azure/login@v1                            # Azure login required to add a temporary firewall rule
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - uses: azure/sql-action@v2
      with:        
        connection-string: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING }}
        path: './script.sql'
```

and now you need to create 2 files in your github directory.

first file `Database.sqlproj` and here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.Sql" Version="0.1.3-preview" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Name>reactions</Name>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    <ModelCollation>1033, CI</ModelCollation>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

second file  `script.sql` and here is the code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProductNumber] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [StandardCost] [money] NOT NULL,
    [ListPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Weight] [decimal](8, 2) NULL,
    [ProductCategoryID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductModelID] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

and here is, how you can make the connection string and save it into the github secrets.

```
Place the connection string from the Azure Portal in GitHub secrets as AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING. Connection string format is: 
Server=<server.database.windows.net>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Initial Catalog=<database>.
```